# Pycharm is not allowing me to make a password for a super user on my Django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, passwords, superuser

I am trying to create a superuser on the terminal on pycharm but It's not typing anyting when I try to create a password for that superuser in the terminal.

I tried to recall the command "python manage.py createsuperuser" a few times but I still ran into the same issue. I was expecting it to type in the password, but no matter what I type it's not typing anything. I am following this tutorial: [Python Tutorial-Python Full Course For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc) and my issue is at 5 hrs and 38 mins. I am able to type in the username and email, but just not the password.

Comment: Can you post `manage.py`? Without it not possible to know what is happening in code.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out on my own, so for anyone who is also having this issue, there actually isn't one. Basically, the PyCharm Terminal doesn't actually show the password when you're typing it. So just try typing in whatever password you like and press enter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).